# How to drag a UIButton outlet to the button?

Tags: iphone, button

I want to enable or disable the button. Is there any way to drag the outlet of UIButton on to the Bar Button? I tried, I could do that. How to enable or disable the button if I can't connection them together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the `UIBarButtonItem`.